# JavaScript - audio src - replace URL with variable

Tags: javascript

I've looked up similar questions, but haven't been able to make this work.  Sorry if this is a basic question.

This works for me with an on-click button:

```
var player = document.createElement('audio');
player.src = 'http://jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg';
player.load();
player.play();
```

How can I replace the URL with a variable - "sound1", where the variable fetches a different URL? I tried this for the 2nd line, to no avail:

```
player.src = "'" + sound1 +"'";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `"` or `'`. Just use

```
player.src = sound1;
```

Assuming that sound1 just holds an URL.

For example:

```js
var sound1 = 'http://jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg';
var player = document.createElement('audio');
player.src = sound1;
player.load();
player.play();
```